# VNC Client & Server on 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, vnc, client

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 (fresh install from 20.04.1 & software up to date) on my new main fast computer. I want to desktop share my old NUC Barebones computer, running Xubuntu 20.04 (fresh install from 20.04.1 and software up to date] which I want to use for limited activities such as ip camera usage (using motion app) and VPN away from home. I don't really care much which VNC Client & Server apps I use. So I'm trying Remmina on my Ubuntu 20.04 main fast computer and VNC Server Connect on my old NUC Barebones computer. However, connection fails from the VNC Client to the VNC Server. I've tried in Remmina both RDP & Remmina VNC Plugin.
PS I'm happy to use other VNC apps if they will work.